# What is the meaning of [array name] in C language?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int array[3][3] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    printf("%d\n", array[1][-2]); // 2
    printf("%d\n", (-1)[array][5]);  // 3
    printf("%d\n", -1[array][5]);  // -9

    return 0;  
}
```

What is the meaning of [array]? why output 3? -9?  thank you!

Comment: 1) arrays are stored in contiguous memory 2) read about pointer arithmetic.

Comment: While the duplicate answers the issue about the weird notation where `array[index]` is also equal to `index[array]`, your code does contain a few other things that makes it bad and technically *undefined behavior* as you go out of bounds of your arrays. Where did you find this example? Please don't use that source again.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Where does the code go outside the bounds? All three examples result in an address inside the bounds of the given array. `[1][-2]` is equivalent to `[0][3-2]`, `[-1][5]` is equivalent to `[0][5-3]` and `[1][5]` is `[2][5-3]`.

Comment: @glglgl `array` is an array of three arrays of three `int`. That means `array[1]` is an array of three `int`. The index `-2` is out of bound of that array. Yes it's "in bounds" of the memory for the whole of `array`, but for `array[1]` is it out of bounds. The same for index `5` or `-1`. The code as shown is simply bad and doesn't show anything useful IMO.

Comment: Array values will be calculated from head address that is array, since it is a pointer,
 not `array[i][j] = *(array + (i*(n)+j)sizeof(type))` .
So in case 1 array + 1*3 - 2 i.e. array + 1, values at this address is 2.
But this is a really bad practice to use negative indices

Comment: Also very important here is the issue of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: I know that for a two-dimensional array int arr[M][N], the address of arr[i][j] is (*arr) + i * N + j, and its value is * ((*arr) + i * N + j), I didn't know a[5] == 5[a] before, thank you all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, I didn't know that this is important as well. I always thought that would be ok because the three arrays are by definition adjacent to each other. But even if it was valid, it would be bad style, granted.

Answer (score 1):

In C, given two expressions `E1` and `E2`, the syntax:

```
E1[E2]
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
E2[E1]
```